# Count occurrences of character in a string Haskell

Tags: haskell

Trying to determine how to count the occurrences of a `char` is a `string`. I was it to be stored in a list `[char,count]`.

`countChars :: String -> [(Char, Int)]`

I'm new and learning Haskell so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I guess, you're supposed to solve this using [recursion](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion)?

Comment: @mb21 I assume so. I've just started learning haskell and it is throwing me for such a loop since I have only ever used Object Oriented languages rather than functional.

Comment: @ZackHerbert , can you show what have you tried, and where did you stuck?

Comment: @utdemir I honestly don't know where to begin. Its all foreign to me

Comment: You're going to have to make *some* effort. Do you know how to define a function? Do you know about pattern matching?  Do you know *anything* about Haskell?

Comment: This looks like homework. Even if its self-study, the same principles apply. Read this first. Then edit your question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions?lq=1

Answer (score 4):

to give you a taste

```
> (map (head &&& length) . group . sort) "asdfasdfaeadf"
[('a',4),('d',3),('e',1),('f',3),('s',2)]
```

after bunch or imports.

You can easily define your head &&& length, if that syntax is unfamiliar.

```
> head_and_length x = (head x, length x)
```

group can be written recursively

```
group [] = []
group (x:xs) = (x:ys) : group zs
    where (ys,zs) = (takeWhile (==x) xs, dropWhile (==x) xs)
```

take as many matching elements as possible and recursively apply on the remaining elements until nothing left.  Note that this definition requires same elements to be contiguous, that's why a sort is required.

Writing a complex function is one piece is not recommended, it's better to implement small features separately (and perhaps use the existing functions) which can be independently tested and create a composition of these as a final solution.

Comment: That's somewhat horrifying even for an intermediate Haskell programmer (even assuming they know where `&&&` comes from); this is in no way helpful to someone just starting out.

Comment: I disagree, coming up with this solution requires experience but not for understanding.  Looking at the result you can see that mapped function produces a pair with a char and int, it's clear where they are coming from.  Similarly, to count each occurrence, sorting and grouping them should be intuitive and easier than a recursive solution.

Comment: I actually like this solution, and find it readable, but perhaps it's too much for a beginner.

Comment: I'm with @chepner. You're introducing three separate concepts in a single line each of which is probably new to a beginner: arrows, currying, and the equivalent of point-free syntax (composing all the functions together). The clarification afterwards is good, but I would caution that throwing so much at a novice only cements the (unfair) impression of Haskell as an intimidating language. Maybe the clunky way first and the one liner last (with a note to not worry about it too much until later) would be a better order.

Comment: I've rescinded my down vote following the additional explanation, but I still think this is too much for someone who hasn't explained *what* they need help with.

Comment: Right, the goal was to show that the main task can be thought of a composition of smaller pieces.  I didn't include the import statements to discourage copy/paste programming.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to be helpful, but it is going to be fast. The trick is to use an `IntMap`, a very efficient representation of maps with `Int` keys, to store how many of each character have been seen. We're using *characters* for keys, so we start by creating a `CharMap` type wrapping up an `IntMap` and writing some functions that wrap up their `IntMap` equivalents.

```
import Data.Foldable (Foldable, foldl')
import Control.Applicative ((<|>))
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as IM
import Data.IntMap (IntMap)

-- Strict version of Data.Bifunctor.first
first :: (a -> a') -> (a, b) -> (a', b)
first f (a, b) = (f a, b)

newtype CharMap a = CharMap (IntMap a)

emptyCM :: CharMap a
emptyCM = CharMap (IM.empty)

toAssocAsc :: CharMap a -> [(Char, a)]
toAssocAsc (CharMap m) = map (first toEnum) (IM.toAscList m)

alter :: (Maybe a -> Maybe a) -> Char -> CharMap a -> CharMap a
alter f c (CharMap m) = CharMap $ IM.alter f (fromEnum c) m
```

That was a bit annoying, but rather mechanical. Here's the main event. We toss characters into a `CharMap`, keeping them mapped to their counts, and then convert the map to an association list when we're done.

```
countCharacterOccurrences ::
  Foldable t => t Char -> [(Char, Int)]
countCharacterOccurrences = toAssocAsc . foldl' go emptyCM
  where
    go m c = alter (\curr -> fmap (+1) curr <|> Just 1) c m
```